# 'Invalid Client' response after replacing cURL with CakePHP 3 Http Client

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I am trying to update my CakePHP 3.5 controller to use the Cake Http Client instead of the following cURL code:

```
private function executeRequest($url, $parameters = array(), $http_header, $http_method)
{

  $curl_options = array();

  switch($http_method){
        case self::HTTP_METHOD_GET:
          $curl_options[CURLOPT_HTTPGET] = 'true';
          if (is_array($parameters) && count($parameters) > 0) {
            $url .= '?' . http_build_query($parameters);
          } elseif ($parameters) {
            $url .= '?' . $parameters;
          }
          break;
        case self:: HTTP_METHOD_POST:
          $curl_options[CURLOPT_POST] = '1';
          if(is_array($parameters) && count($parameters) > 0){
            $body = http_build_query($parameters);
            $curl_options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $body;
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
  }
  /**
  * An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')
  */
  if(is_array($http_header)){
        $header = array();
        foreach($http_header as $key => $value) {
            $header[] = "$key: $value";
        }
        $curl_options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $header;
  }

  $curl_options[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
  // Require SSL Certificate

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  //Don't display, save it on result
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  //Execute the Curl Request
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  $headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT );

  $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
   if ($curl_error = curl_error($ch)) {
       throw new Exception($curl_error);
   }
   else {
       $json_decode = json_decode($result, true);
   }
   curl_close($ch);

   return $json_decode;
}
```

The updated code is:

```
private function executeRequest($url, $http_header, $http_method, $parameters = array())
{
    $htclient = new Client();
    $response = null;

  switch($http_method){
        case self::HTTP_METHOD_GET:
          if (is_array($parameters) && count($parameters) > 0) {
            $params = http_build_query($parameters);
          } elseif ($parameters) {
            $params = $parameters;
          }
          $response = $htclient->get($url, ['q' => $params], ['headers' => $http_header]);
          break;
        case self::HTTP_METHOD_POST:
          if(is_array($parameters) && count($parameters) > 0){
            $response = $htclient->post($url, $parameters, ['headers' => $http_header]);
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
  }

  return $response->json;

}
```

When I attempt to use the `POST` function, the return code is `error: invalid client`.
the headers for `POST` are:

```
   $http_header = array(
     'Accept' => 'application/json',
     'Authorization' => $authorizationHeaderInfo,
     'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   );
```

and the content array is:

```
   $parameters = array(
     'grant_type' => $grant_type,
     'code' => $code,
     'redirect_uri' => $redirectUrl
   );
```

These are the same arrays that were used in the `cURL` code.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem wasn't with the `CakePHP Client`, I found where I had accidentally changed the calling function during the update.